# How can I fill all the most occurring numbers and their indices?

Tags: java, arrays

Problem:

Write a Java program in a console application that will allow a user to enter the size of an integer array. The program will then repeatedly ask for number inputs stored in an array, display all the numbers from the array, including indices, and determine the most occurring number with its indices. If there is more than one most-occurring number, all those numbers and indices will also be displayed. The program should allow the user to repeat the execution.

Code that I have made so far in my main method:

```java
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.print("Enter the size of integer array: ");
        int num = sc.nextInt();

        int[] arr = new int [num];

        System.out.println("\nEnter the Elements: ");
        for (int x = 0; x < num; x++) {
            System.out.print("Element #" + (x + 1) + ": ");
            arr[x] = sc.nextInt();
        }

        System.out.println("\nArray Values: ");
        for (int x = 0; x < num; x++) {
            System.out.println("Numbers [" + x + "] = " + arr[x]);
        }

        int theMaxCount = 0;
        int[] theMostOccurringIndices = new int[num];
        int theCurrentIndex = 0;

        for (int x = 0; x < num; x++) {
            int theCurrentCount = 1;

            for (int y = x + 1; y < num; y++) {
                if (arr[x] == arr[y]) {
                    theCurrentCount++;
                }
            }

            if (theCurrentCount > 1 && theCurrentCount >= theMaxCount) {
                if (theCurrentCount > theMaxCount) {
                    theMaxCount = theCurrentCount;
                    theCurrentIndex = 0;
                }
                theMostOccurringIndices[theCurrentIndex++] = x;
            }
        }

        System.out.println("\nThe most occurring numbers and their indices are: ");
        for (int x = 0; x < theCurrentIndex; x++) {
            System.out.println("num[" + theMostOccurringIndices[x] + "] = " + arr[theMostOccurringIndices[x]]);
        }

        System.out.print("\nNumber of counts: " + theMaxCount);

        System.out.print("\nDo you want to repeat the program execution? (Y/N): ");
        char decision = sc.next().charAt(0);
        if (decision == 'Y' || decision == 'y') {
            main(args);
        } else {
            System.out.println("Program Terminated.");
        }
```

The output (as of my point of view):

```
Enter the size of integer array: 5

Enter the Elements:
Element #1: 1
Element #2: 2
Element #3: 3
Element #4: 1
Element #5: 5

Array Values:
Numbers [0] = 1
Numbers [1] = 2
Numbers [2] = 3
Numbers [3] = 1
Numbers [4] = 5

The most occurring numbers and their indices are:
num[0] = 1

Number of counts: 2
Do you want to repeat the program execution? (Y/N): N
Program Terminated.
```

The supposed output of my problem:

```
Enter the size of integer array: 5

Enter the Elements:
Element #1: 1
Element #2: 2
Element #3: 3
Element #4: 1
Element #5: 5

Array Values:
Numbers [0] = 1
Numbers [1] = 2
Numbers [2] = 3
Numbers [3] = 1
Numbers [4] = 5

The most occurring numbers and their indices are:
num[0] = 1
num[3] = 1

Number of counts: 2
Do you want to repeat the program execution? (Y/N): N
Program Terminated.
```

So in overall, how can the logic input all of how it is going to fill all the most occurring numbers and their indices that will not be like at my output as of my point of view?

Comment: The last sentence is close to incomprehensible (due to [machine translation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_Translate)?). Can you rephrase it, please? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Re *"point of view"*: Is that also from machine translation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue with this approach is that you count the occurrences of the number, but then you only add the first index in your outer loop. Then it starts the count over and even if it is the same number it will never reach the max count again because it does not consider the earlier index.

A better approach may be to add the value that occurs most in the array:

```
int theMaxCount = 0;
int[] theMostOccurringNumber = new int[num];
int theCurrentIndex = 0;
    
for (int x = 0; x < num; x++) {
    int theCurrentCount = 1;
        
    for (int y = x + 1; y < num; y++) {
        if (arr[x] == arr[y]) {
            theCurrentCount++;
        }
    }
        
    if (theCurrentCount > 1 && theCurrentCount >= theMaxCount) {
        if (theCurrentCount > theMaxCount) {
            theMaxCount = theCurrentCount;
            theCurrentIndex = 0;
        }
        theMostOccurringNumber[theCurrentIndex++] = arr[x];
    }
}
```

Then loop through and print the index where it matches that value:

```
System.out.println("\nThe most occurring numbers and their indices are: ");
for (int x = 0; x < theCurrentIndex; x++) {
    for(int y = 0; y < num; y++) {
        if(arr[y] == theMostOccurringNumber[x]) {
            System.out.println("num[" + y + "] = " + theMostOccurringNumber[x]);
        }
    }
}
```